# Grails Unit Testing occurring on Wrong Phase of Maven Life Cycle

Tags: maven, unit-testing, grails

I'm trying to run unit tests on a Grails app and they happen to run during the verify phase of our maven life cycle as opposed to the test phase (To be clear the maven life cycle goes as: "clean"->"validate"->"compile"->"test"->"package"->"verify"->"install"->"site"->"deploy"). Is there any way to re-associate the plugins responsible for testing (i.e. grails:test-app) to the "test" phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run grails tests from execution plugin, you can specify phase:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Unit-test-app</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>grails</executable>
                        <commandlineArgs>test-app -unit --non-interactive </commandlineArgs>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
</build>
```